# Is the Nehemiah in Ezra 2:2 the one who wrote the book of Nehemiah?

Tags: ezra

Ezra 2:2

> They came with Zerubbabel, Jeshua, Nehemiah, Seraiah, Reelaiah, Mordecai, Bilshan, Mispar, Bigvai, Rehum, and Baanah. The number of the men of the people of Israel:

Is this the same Nehemiah who wrote the book of Nehemiah?

Answer (score 1):

The first return of Jews from Babylonian captivity occurred about 538/537 BC in the first regnal year of Cyrus (Ezra 1:1-4).  However, the Nehemiah who rebuilt the walls of Jerusalem in  was during the reign of Artaxerxes about 90 years later.

Note the comments the Cambridge commentary on Ezra 2:2 -

> Nehemiah] not to be confounded with the better known Nehemiah, who
> rebuilt the walls of Jerusalem 90 years later, 445 b.c.